# Difference between 'enrage' and 'get somebody angry'

Tags: word-difference

What difference, if any, is there between between *enrage* and *get somebody angry* ?

> New tax policy will do nothing but enrage people.
>   New tax policy will do nothing but get people angry.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any dictionary entries you checked, and the reasons those didn't resolve your confusion.

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/66047/difference-between-logo-and-emblem I took this question as an example

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't think you get the site's question policy. I recommend you take a tour which I did when I register and saw this kind of question was given an example question on the site. http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: The example question includes some idea of what the asker thinks the two words are about, a starting point. It's not necessarily quite as good as dictionary entries, but it's not bad. (I would recommend you refrain from telling other users what they do or do not understand about the site's policies until you have some experience here.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't need experience and I would recommend you refrain from telling other users what they do or do not understand about the site's policies until you get it right

Comment: @NathanTuggy my question is completely eligible according to the example given by the site.

Comment: @kyle There is no need to be harsh. I believe that Nathan Tuggy's comment was clearly in good faith, and for the benefit of your question. A better question will have better chances to get better answers.

Comment: @DamkerngT. sorry if I sound rude.I don't think I was harsh, I just tried to teach him the site's policies which he got it wrong because it is likely he has not read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New tax policy will do nothing but make (get) people angry.

New tax policy will do nothing but will make people very angry = enrage people.

Comment: so you mean the same ?

Comment: There's a difference between making somebody angry and making somebody very angry.

Comment: opps :)) sorry my eyes had lost between lines. got it now